# I am trying to access Phpmyadmin and look & create databases but I am not able to login

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am working to get access to phpmyadmin by using Xampp on my windows 10. I am unable to login. I have tried many things which includes:

1) delete "ib_logfile0" and ib_logfile1
2) Restarting machine
3) Changing username and password and trying that in the below code
4) making 'AllowNoPassword' true and false both in below code.
5) checking skype and all ports

I am confused now what can I do. I am new to php and mysql and don't know much of codes. I am attaching my Xampp interface also below:
[image]

Code in my config.inc.php

```
    /* Authentication type and info */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']    = 'cookie';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']         = 'root';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']     = '';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
    $cfg['Lang'] = '';

    /* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

    /* User for advanced features */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']  = 'root';   
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']  = '';
```

[image]

Comment: In which direcory you installed xampp ?

Comment: In c directly. Btw, it got resolved with the first answer.

Comment: To Fred and Jay,  I have seen that question, but none of the solutions there worked. I finally got the solution from one of the answer here. SO it is a little different than that. Please understand someone's problem when the person is beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please define the new port number in mysql configuration when you change from default port no 3306. From the xampp panel I could see that the port of mysql is 3307.
Or in phpmyadmin:
In configuration change host as '127.0.0.1:3307'

If default port is not changed in configuration of my.ini(mysql configuration file),  you have to mention the port no. in every mysql connection request.

Hope it helps.